# Can you access the mp3 files of songs you've purchased on the iTunes Store?

Tags: android, itunes-store, music.app, mp3

I'd like to purchase several mp3s to download to my Android phone on the iTunes Store on my Mac (due to the fact that I don't want to buy entire CDs for a single track or use an online service for them). However, I don't have the Apple Music app on my Android, and would like to be able to use the purchased mp3s on my phone nonetheless. **Is it possible to download and copy the mp3 files of purchased songs from the iTunes Store?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can export the purchased song (AAC format) to mp3 and then transfer to your android device.
Please follow this guide: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204310

Thanks